# Determine WCF client timeout setting on server

Tags: wcf, timeout

Is it possible to determine the client timeout values on the server? I am in the unfortunate position that I have a long running WCF service (about 90 seconds) and I would like to know beforehand if the client is going to time out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you force the client to tell you what his timeout is, you have no way of knowing that.
You could kindly ask for the information, adding a method parameter, or header.

You could also try to break your long running call into smaller parts, forcing the client to make subsequent calls if your business allows.

You could use asynchronous calls with a callback, one way method / duplex channels.

There are other possibilities, but we need to know more about your environment.

Comment: Thanks Paciv, I thought as much. I can't easily break it up and the client side isn't very flexible, but I will look into forcing an asynchronous call.